# AWS lambda invoke sometimes hangs indefinitely when executed via ECS

Tags: java, aws-lambda, amazon-ecs, aws-java-sdk

I have an spring boot app which is invoking lambda functions via aws-java-sdk-lambda like so:

```
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.AWSLambda;
...

InvokeResult result = awsLambda.invoke(invokeRequest);
```

Now when I'm running this from my local machine, this works fine: it invokes the function and then returns a response when it completes. Sometimes, the lambda function times out, and in that scenario, I get a response indicating this.

I also have this app deployed in an ECS task, and I've noticed that, in that context, if the lambda function doesn't take more than 10 mins to complete, I get a response just as expected. However, if it takes much longer than that or if it ultimately times out after 15 mins, the invoke method hangs indefinitely in the ECS task (whereas locally I always get a response back after 15 mins at the latest - indicating a timeout).

In order to address this I've tried adjusting the ClientConfiguration so that it times out after 16 mins, however, this solution won't work since sometimes the lambda function completes after about 10 mins and the invoke method still hangs indefinitely in the ECS task  (though, again, this never happens for me when running the app locally).

I considered whether this could be permission related, however, that doesn't seem likely. The task has "lambda:InvokeFunction" and "lambda:GetFunction" permissions and does behave as expected when the lambda function completes in under 10 mins. Is there anything else I should try to prevent the invocation from hanging?

Comment: Similar behavior with pure nodejs lamda function. It takes aprox 4 min. The task always is completed but sometimes the return answer never reaches the target

Answer (score 0):

There is not a lot of information in the question to give you a proper answer.

From what I understood from your question you are executing a lambda and sometimes it completes and other times it times out. If this is in fact the case it most likely isn't a connectivity problem, so the problem should be the lambda design/performance.

A quick thing I would try first - if you didn’t yet - would be to increase the Lambda available memory (I think the default is 128MB). Increasing the available memory can significantly increase your Lambda performance. [[Source]](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/operating-lambda-performance-optimization-part-2/)

A couple of other tips that might be useful for you to debug your problem:

1. **Review Lambda Design/Performance**: Examine the code and execution
   logic of your Lambda function to ensure it is optimized for
   performance. Look for any potential bottlenecks or long-running
   operations that could be causing the function to exceed the timeout
   limit. Also make sure you take advantage of [execution environment reuse](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/best-practices.html#function-code) whenever
   possible.
2. **Check for Dependencies or External API Calls**: If your Lambda
   function relies on other AWS services or external APIs, verify if
   any of these dependencies are causing delays or timeouts. Monitor
   the logs of the Lambda function to identify any potential issues
   with these external interactions.
3. **Analyse Lambda Function Logs**: Enable detailed logging within your
   Lambda function and review the logs to gain insights into its
   execution behaviour. Look for any error messages, warnings, or
   performance-related information that could help diagnose the hanging
   behaviour.
4. **Check AWS Service Limits**: Confirm that you have not exceeded any
   [service limits](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/gettingstarted-limits.html) for AWS Lambda that could be affecting the
   behaviour. For example, check if you have reached the maximum
   concurrent executions.
5. **Consider Alternative Solutions**: If your workload requires longer
   processing times beyond the 15-minute limit imposed by Lambda,
   consider alternative AWS services such as another ECS task or even EC2 to handle those workloads. These services offer more control
   over the computing
   environment and allow for longer execution times.

However, for a better understanding of what exactly might be happenning it would be useful if you could share the code (or the part of the code that you think has problems). If the code is proprietary a pseudo-code version or an explanation may also be useful.